# What file in Windows 7 corresponds to the linux file ssl.so?

Tags: ruby, linux, ssl, windows-7

The problem appears to be that in Linux, OpenSSL includes a file ssl.so, but Windows OpenSSL does not have the equivalent file.

I have a ruby program that runs fine on Ubuntu 12.04 but fails on Windows 7 with the message:

```
 C:\Ruby200-x64\code>ruby ssl-bug.rb
 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:154:in `blo
 ck in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'ssl': The specified module could not be
  (LoadError)
 .
 Could not open library 'ssl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
         from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.1/lib/ffi/library.r
 b:121:in `map'
         from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.1/lib/ffi/library.r
 b:121:in `ffi_lib'
         from ssl-bug.rb:5:in `<module:OpenSSL_EC>'
         from ssl-bug.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Here is a short example (ssl-bug.rb) of the kind of program which runs on Ubuntu 12.04 fine, but not on Windows 7, generating the error above:

```
 require 'ffi'

 module OpenSSL_EC  
   extend FFI::Library
   ffi_lib 'ssl'
 end
```

Comment: What exported functions do you need?

Comment: ECDSA functions to generate a public key from a private key.

Comment: maybe it's called "libssl32.dll" or its like...

Comment: [ECDSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1 "msdn: ECDSA class") seems to be definitely part of the latest .Net runtime version which is far to be installed everywhere...

Answer (score 3):

The ECSDA functions are in the OpenSSL file "libeay32.dll". You can see this if you examine that dll's exports. Here I used "dumpbin" from a Visual Studio command line:

```
> dumpbin /exports libeay32.dll
```

Which produces this output:

```
...
Dump of file libeay32.dll
...
ordinal hint RVA      name
...
   3620  2CD 00044030 ECDSA_OpenSSL
   3455  2CE 00044BC0 ECDSA_SIG_free
   3395  2CF 00044BA0 ECDSA_SIG_new
   3440  2D0 00044C40 ECDSA_do_sign
   3671  2D1 00044BE0 ECDSA_do_sign_ex
   3672  2D2 00044DE0 ECDSA_do_verify
   3522  2D3 00044EF0 ECDSA_get_default_method
   3509  2D4 00045330 ECDSA_get_ex_data
   3744  2D5 00045270 ECDSA_get_ex_new_index
   3625  2D6 00044EE0 ECDSA_set_default_method
   3739  2D7 000452A0 ECDSA_set_ex_data
   3731  2D8 00045100 ECDSA_set_method
   3719  2D9 00044D00 ECDSA_sign
   3403  2DA 00044C80 ECDSA_sign_ex
   3416  2DB 00044D80 ECDSA_sign_setup
   3706  2DC 000451A0 ECDSA_size
   3666  2DD 00044E40 ECDSA_verify
```

So on Windows you will have to use `libeay32` instead of `ssl` in your Ruby code:

```
require 'ffi'

module OpenSSL_EC  
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'libeay32'
end
```

That is as far as I can get you as I am unfamiliar with FFI.

Comment: It won't work for peoples which won't have Openssl installed or if it is not bundled in an installer with his application. He/She is asking for the windows equivalent.

Comment: @user2284570 - Unless I missed it, the OP never says that OpenSSL won't or can't be installed.

Comment: This is looking promising. I will investigate further later.

Comment: This is starting to go somewhere: I get

C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:282:in `att
ach_function': Function 'SSL_library_init' not found in [libeay32] (FFI::NotFoun
dError)

which is odd given that your function dump shows it should be there. I'll try to get a more recent libeay32

Comment: Except it doesn't. I was reading a source file rather than this page.

Comment: @KeirFinlow-Bates `SSL_library_init` is in the other file libssl32.dll. I'm not really familiar with OpenSSL either and can't tell you why the Windows version is split into two library files.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I just found that now too: C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:282:in `att
ach_function': Function 'ERR_load_crypto_strings' not found in [libssl32] (FFI::
NotFoundError) when I replace ssl in the ruby library with libssl32.dll

Comment: @KeirFinlow-Bates - Well `ERR_load_CRYPTO_strings` is in the first library (libeay32). It is likely you will need to have both libraries loaded.. I can't tell you whether FFI can do that.

Comment: Okay, I've got to the point where the functions I require are attached by referencing both libssl32.dll and libeay32.dll. Thanks chue.

Comment: If you really want to check, there is Dependency walker (depends.exe) available from Microsoft Support tools. It let you see exported symbols in PE file and see if all importation entries can be satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

I think installing openssl should help you. Btw, i've never wrote anything in ruby.

Comment: The first thing I tried on getting the error was installing OpenSSL, and the Windows rubyinstaller.org installation provides some SSL files with gem install ssl. Just not ssl.dll, and the files provided even if renamed don't work.

Answer (score -2):

Windows and Unix based OS are completely two different things. Windows 7 is an NT Os with an NT subsystem (or two if x86_64) which consist of WIN32 (+ WIN64 if you can run 64-bit PEs).
The windows subsystem give a a well defined set of API which is called [WINAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433218%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which don't contains things like .NET or DirectX). For example The API for dealing with Networking API is called Winsock.
The main API for cryptgraphic Api is called [CyptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/aa380255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (See Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/aa388162(v=vs.85).aspx). Most Of it's functions are located in %SystemRoot%\System32\[Crypt32.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (unless you're using 32-bits binaries on 64-bits windows version).
I tried to look for SSL functions/c++ classes, but I didn't found them yet (Maybe there are part of .Net or something else)

Actually, you don't want to use the windows subsystem Native functions. Your're trying to get ruby running under windows. I don't know which compiler you're using, but it doesn't seems to be cl (which is used in Microsoft Visual Studio). OpenSSL are an API which provide cryptography C Functions. Windows is using different ones So, It won't work since it is OpenSSL functions the linker is looking for in SSL shared objects files.

What you're currently wanting to use programs which are written for using API's present in Unix OS like POSIX.

Microsoft designed several things for this:
[SUA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/cc771470.aspx) will give a base system with X11 gcc and make. Many libraries required to compile ruby will be missing. So, you'll probably want to search some pre-compiled [packages](http://web.archive.org/web/20130406032142/http://www.suacommunity.com/SUA.aspx) on this [site](http://web.archive.org/web/20130406032130/http://www.suacommunity.com/).

Another approach is to make the system recognize the ELF format and wrap linux systems calls which allow to run [linux binaries](http://lbw.sourceforge.net/) without emulation. But since you're using windows 7, the sentence is "too bad for you" [:)](http://atratus.org/)

Comment: I know Windows and UNIX are different. That is why I am using the Ruby FFI library in order to write my extension - as "An FFI extension is multi-platform and multi-implementation".

I am not "trying to get ruby running under Windows". I have ruby running both under Windows and under Linux, and it's working on both, except that the dynamic library ssl.so under Linux doesn't seem to have a corresponding dynamic library ssl.dll under Windows.

Comment: Again: If you read correctly my post, you should understand that openSSL functions don't exist in windows. %SystemRoot%\System32\crypt32.dll don't have all native windows crypto functions/c++ classes and moreover that ssl funct are maybe part of add-ons such as .Net runtime. If you want to use openssl functions, you should use an Unix environment. Microsoft designed SUA on top of windows for that purpose. If you really want to go ahead, then you may consider crypt32.dll as something which can look (from far) as an equivalent of ssl.so, but it will not solve your problems.

Comment: openSSL is available for Windows, as the commentor above pointed out (and I installed it). At the moment I am running my program using a Linux environment, but it should be possible to run it using a Windows environment too - that's meant to be the idea behind cross-platform support.

Comment: Sorry, but even by Using OpenSSL for windows, you'll use an Unix environment: current binaries implementations will use MainGW or cygwin (most programs use them). Those work without creating an NT subsystem so it mean convert POSIX->WinAPI->NT API. By Using Microsoft implementations, you'll still use the windows subsystem, but certain part's will use the NT API. If you're lazy, you can bundles the openssl dlls with cygwin ones in you app. Real porting from POSIX to WINAPI mean rewrite near from scratch. [:)](http://atratus.org/ "You may bundle this in your installer with your linux version")